# Conversion of data frame to time series causing character vectors to be coerced to NAs

Tags: r, list, time-series, character, na

Earlier I was having a problem where each observation for each independent variable was a coefficient in my model, but I'm asking a different question now, because I believe that it's caused by a preceding issue. I've also provided a sample of my data, per MrFlick's suggestion. I am running RStudio Version 1.1.453

I have a list of data frames that contains both numbers and strings:

```
structure(list(Week = structure(1:10, .Label = c("2018-01-22", 
"2018-01-29", "2018-02-05", "2018-02-12", "2018-02-19", "2018-02-26", 
"2018-03-05", "2018-03-12", "2018-03-19", "2018-03-26"), class = "factor"), 
    Org = c("DAN", "DAN", "DAN", "DAN", "DAN", "DAN", "DAN", 
    "DAN", "DAN", "DAN"), Actual = c(30000L, 30000L, 30000L, 
    30000L, 30000L, 30000L, 30000L, 30000L, 30000L, 30000L), 
    Int.Ext = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = "Int", class = "factor"), prevAccuracy = c(107.6938982, 
    109.1514083, 111.5342724, 5.9778739, 4.5426629, 1.3922019, 
    0.9047371, 0.6584585, 0.6369323, 0.6631414)), row.names = c("4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"), class = "data.frame")
```

And when I try to convert it into time-series data, variables that are characters get converted into `NA`s, and variables that are factors get converted into factor levels:

```
  > str(frames[[1]])
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Week        : Factor w/ 10 levels "2018-01-22","2018-01-29",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ Org         : chr  "DAN" "DAN" "DAN" "DAN" ...
 $ Actual      : int  30000 30000 30000 30000 30000 30000 30000 30000 30000 30000
 $ Int.Ext     : Factor w/ 1 level "Int": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ prevAccuracy: num  107.69 109.15 111.53 5.98 4.54 ...

frames1 <- ts(frames[[1]], freq=365.25/7, start=2018 + 22/365.25)
```

Upon converting `frames` into time-series, I also get this warning message `In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion`. Is it possible to keep character variables when I convert these data frames into time series? If so, how do I do that? I guess a workaround would be to keep the strings as factors, but ideally I would not like to do that.